# Running two seperate Django site from one apache

Tags: python, django, apache, apache2, virtualhost

I am running Ubuntu 14.04 on my notebook and I am using Django 1.6.4 (with virtualenv) together with Apache 2.4.7.

I would like to access two django projects through my local apache. Therefore, theses projects are called `kleyboldt` (name of a guy I am writing for) and `kleyboldt2`. Normally I store my web projects under `/home/nick/Workspace/Web`. After watching tutorial I ended up with two domains pointing to the same django project. To be sure I rewrote the config and placed my projects under `/var/www`.

At the beginning I wrote two files in order to configure apache.

**/etc/apache/sites-available/kleyboldt.conf**

```
WSGIPythonPath /var/www/kleyboldt:/var/www/kleyboldt/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages

<VirtualHost *:80>
    WSGIScriptAlias / /var/www/kleyboldt/kleyboldt.wsgi

    ServerName kleyboldt.com

    Alias /static /var/www/kleyboldt/static

    <Directory /var/www/kleyboldt/>
        Require all granted
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

**/etc/apache2/sites-available/kleyboldt2.conf**

```
WSGIPythonPath /var/www/kleyboldt2:/var/www/kleyboldt2/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages

<VirtualHost *:80>
    WSGIScriptAlias / /var/www/kleyboldt2/kleyboldt2.wsgi

    ServerName kleyboldt2.com

    Alias /static /var/www/kleyboldt2/static

    <Directory /var/www/kleyboldt2/>
        Require all granted
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Afterwards I enabled both sites via `a2ensite`. I checked the `sites-enabled` directory and the links are placed correctly. In order to redirect `kleyboldt.com` and `kleyboldt2.com` to my local apache I changed my **/etc/hosts** to:

```
127.0.0.1   localhost
127.0.1.1   mars (name of my computer)
127.0.0.1   kleyboldt.com
127.0.0.1   kleyboldt2.com
```

To use WSGI I wrote for each project a seperated wsgi file in the project folder:

**/var/www/kleyboldt/kleyboldt.wsgi**

```
import os
import sys

sys.path.append('/var/www/kleyboldt')
os.environ['DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE'] = 'kleyboldt.settings'

import django.core.handlers.wsgi
application = django.core.handlers.wsgi.WSGIHandler()
```

**/var/www/kleyboldt2/kleyboldt2.wsgi**

```
import os
import sys

sys.path.append('/var/www/kleyboldt2')
os.environ['DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE'] = 'kleyboldt2.settings'

import django.core.handlers.wsgi
application = django.core.handlers.wsgi.WSGIHandler()
```

I created two independent python environments using `virtualenv` that are now located under `/var/www/kleyboldt/env` and `/var/www/kleyboldt2/env`.

Afterwarsd I got two django test sites when I typed both domains in the URL bar of my browser. To differ I added some settings to the `settings.py` files and wrote custom views.

**/var/www/kleyboldt/homepage/views.py**

```
from django.http import HttpResponse

def hello(request):
    return HttpResponse("kleyboldt1")
```

**/var/www/kleyboldt2/homepage/views.py**

```
from django.http import HttpResponse

def hello(request):
    return HttpResponse("kleyboldt2")
```

When I type `localhost` in my browser then I get *kleyboldt2* back. When I type `kleyboldt2.com` in my browser then I get *kleyboldt2* back too. Unfortunately I see *kleyboldt2* also after typing `kleyboldt.com` in my browser.

Maybe the bug is to simple for me to discover :D Does anybody know a possible solution?

Comment: You may have an issue having 2 different WSGIPythonPath variables. Can you use daemon mode to set the path for each site within their respective virtualhosts (WSGIPythonPath won't work inside virtualhost)? - https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/deployment/wsgi/modwsgi/

Comment: Thank you. I tried to use the daemon mode and it worked. Maybe it would also work if I set one python path in the apache.conf